# How to check if any label on the form contains the word "abc"?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a condition to check if any label contains the word "abc" and if it does, it blocked the button. I have in the form label1, label2, label3 etc.

I tried for the main **Label** to set the check in Contains but there is no such thing.

After defining:

`Label slabel = new Label();`

I"m trying check in "if" but always return error with null.

`if(slabel.Contains("abc"))`

Please help !

Comment: Labels don't change; so why not just disable the button manually? This seems like a terrible idea overall...

Comment: May be you want to check `Text`! try `if(slabel.Text.Contains("abc")`

Comment: In wpf, this can be achieved in Xaml using Triggers without writing code in code behind file.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET this idea is good, because it is used for validation for the registration form. If it contains "- incorrect data" there, it is to block the "Send" button until all data is correct or no label contains "- invalid".

Comment: @DominikNarozynski Is this win forms? and how are the labels being set in the first place?

Comment: Why rely on the label text for that though? I mean, it seems like at some point, you ran a validation check on the data to set the label text to that. Why not disable the button at the same time?

Comment: Is is WPF, @Hack how ?

Comment: @itsme86 how ? Can you help me ?

Comment: `button1.Enabled = false;'

Comment: But users can't change labels; so... I don't understand what you are doing

Comment: @DominikNarożyński I ask how your setting the label because if its hard coded, as in you make the label with a fixed text in XAML then this is pointless.   You know when you create it.  If your building this window from a external data source, then you should have the data prior to the label text being set and as itsme86 has a point out, you shouldn't need to rely on the labels, just use the data at the start.

Comment: either way, thats a problem with the design, and I don't know enough about it.  I will say this, if you want the text from a wpf label then you need to call slabel.content.tostring() to get it.  slabel is the ui object. you need to be looking at its content for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

For `Windows Forms`:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is Label && c.Text.Contains("abc"))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
button1.Enabled = !found;
```

For `WPF`:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this.Content as DependencyObject); i++)
{
    var v = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.Content as DependencyObject, i);
    if (v is Label && (v as Label).Content.ToString().Contains("abc"))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
button.IsEnabled = !found;
```

Comment: Do you really need this piece (c as Label) ?

Comment: I think he's using wpf, in which case this won't work for him.

Comment: Thank you @HusseinGolshani you're great!